# need to display different parts of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

Hi I am trying to make a music player that will play songs on a website through javascript.

I am having problems when im trying to slice the array to take out the songs.

var files = ["roc-boys.mp3", // - Jay Z
             "dirt.mp3", //- Jay Z
             "99.mp3", // - Jay Z
             "feelin-it.mp3", // - Jay Z
        ];

so that is how i have the array laid out.

```
function createAudioElements() {
     files = files.slice(5,9);
    for (f in files) {
        var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"audio/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";



function createAudioElements() {
           files = files.slice(5,9);
           for (f in files) {
           var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"audio/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";

        $("#audio-players").append(audioString);

    }
}


    function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}
```

This is how the songs are being loaded into the html.
Issue is I cant get it to work in more than 1 div.

Any thoughts??

If anyone knows an easier solution to this that would also be appreciated.

Comment: `files = files.slice(5,9);` will clobber files, and you'll no longer have access to the first 5 elements

Comment: `#audio-players` is id, it should be unique so it's expected that this won't work with multiple elements, try using class instead.

Comment: hey guys thansk for the rapid responses! @Jaramandai just gave a snippet of the array i have been using the slice to try to get differnet playlists out of the array.

Comment: what im trying to do is basically use slice to take each artists songs out of the playlist

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov ive tried changing it to a class. it just breaks it :p not having very much luck with that

Comment: even tried just making and calling seperate functions but that wouldnt work either for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems, as I said, using an id will only work with the first element.
Another important issue that you are overriding global `files` list using `slice` function. This means that by calling `createAudioElments` for the first time, it will update `files` array to the new one from 5th to 9th elements and by calling same or `createAudioPlayers` function it will assign an empty array to `files` variable. Please see working example below and let me know if you have any other questions.

```js
var files = new Array(9).fill(1);

function createAudioElements() {
    for (f in files.slice(5,9)) {
           var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"audio/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";

        $(".audio-players").append(audioString);

    }
}


function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files.slice(5,9)) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $(".audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}

createAudioPlayers();
createAudioElements();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="audio-players">
  <span>First player</span>
</div>
<div class="audio-players">
  <span>Second player</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thats amazing! Thank you for taking the time to do that

Comment: it still isnt working on my one though, i think there might be some element in the rest of the script that would need altered from id to class after the change

Comment: <- bit of a JS novice i have to admit :p

Comment: could you have a quick glance over it please?

Comment: it says that the file is too big to paste into here

Comment: Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The line `var files = new Array(9).fill(1);` is used as an example, you should remove it if you have `files` variable with real data. If you still experiencing issues I suggest you find a root of the problem by simplifying functions and replacing it with mocks.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try, thank you very much for your help!